# Regex remove the rest of the words after finding the first number

Tags: regex

I want to remove all the words including the number when the expression finds the first number: example:

```
Input: Hola 4.4.2 como estas

Output: Hola
```

My expression

```
[^(0-9)]*$
```

DEMO: https://regexr.com/7dbl1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Regex:

```
^[^0-9]+
```

**[Online Demo](https://regexr.com/7dbl7)**

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string anchor |
| `[^0-9]+` | any character except: `0` to '9' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression

```
[^(0-9)]*$
```

reads, "match zero or more (`*`) characters in the character class `[^(0-9)]` followed by the end of the string (`$`), where the character class is comprised of all characters other than (`^`) the characters `'('`, `')'` and the digits `'0'` to `'9'`. Right away you see you want the character class to be `[^0-9]`, so let's change your regex to

```
[^0-9]*$
```

The regex engine initially matches `'Hola '` in your string

```
'Hola 4.4.2 como estas'
```

but then finds that the last character in the match (the space) is not the last character in the string, so the match fails. It then does considerable backtracking<sup>1</sup> before it concludes that no match begins before the first `'4'`.

`'4'` does not match but `'.'` does, but it is not at the end of the string so the process continues until  `' como estas'` is matched. That succeeds because the end of that match is at the end of the string.

---

Clearly, to match `'Hola '`, you want to remove the anchor `$` from your regex: `[^0-9]*`.

If you do that there will be seven matches in your string:

- `'Hola '`;
- `'.'` (twice);
- the empty string before each digit (thrice); and
- `' como estas'`.

Presumably you are only interested in the first match, which is fine.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tdxAa8/1)

---

If you were to change your regular expression to

```
[^0-9]+
```

empty strings before each digit would no longer match.

---

If you did not wish to match the space at the end of `'Hola '` you could append a *negative lookbehind* to your regular expression:

```
[^0-9]*(?<! )
```

`(?<! )` reads, "the previous character matched may not be a space".

This of course requires that the regex engine supports lookbehinds.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mmGQM2/1)

<sup>1 See a simulation of the steps performed by the regex engine for your regex by scrolling to the bottom of the left column [here](https://regex101.com/r/tdxAa8/1) and selecting "Regex Debugger"</sup>